# Angular Excluding dynamic *.js import from webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, import

I do the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (this.myCondition) {
      import("../../somePath/myJsFile").then((myModule) => {
        myModule.doSomething();
      }
    }
...
}
```

In this case, the file myJsFile.js and all its dependencies are included in the webpack. But at runtime one file of these dependencies is changed, so that I dont want to include it in the webpack and load it at this moment from the webserver.

How can I define, exclude myJsFile.js and all its dependencies or only one of these dependencies from the builded webpack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clean way of doing this. This defeats the purpose of having immutable and reproducible builds.

Having said this, if you want to still do this, then you can make use of (or, rather exploit the webpack [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) feature).

Support your `myJsFile.js` file depends on a 3rd-party dependency like Rx.js for example. In this case, you can tell webpack that this is external dependency like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ... rest of the webpack configuration
  externals: {
    rxjs: 'rxjs',
  },
};
```

Here the Webpack will not bundle the Rx.js library altogether. At runtime, you will provide this file using CDN or something before loading your bundle. So, your HTML file would be similar to:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.1/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <!-- Your webpack generated javascript bundle -->
  <script src="//app.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `externals` configuration tells Webpack that any code imported from `rxjs` package (key of the `externals` object) would be available at runtime and that the value would be available as `rxjs` global variable (value of the `externals['rxjs']`). Wherever in code, the rxjs is encountered, webpack converts it to:

```js
// Original code
import { map } from 'rxjs';

// Webpack generated code or equivalent
const { map } = globalThis.rxjs;
```

Now, back to your original question, you can use this technique to dynamically load your module from your server similar to how we are loading the dependency using `script` tag and the CDN. Ensure that the request to this dependency is not cached and uses proper `ETag` for optimal caching strategy.

Finally, you will also need to ensure that your dependency properly exposes a global variable with which you can access all the functionality of that module/dependency.